# Mercurial paths in hgrc

Tags: mercurial

I need to know if i it is possible to add in my hgrc file something like this:

```
[paths]
default = http://somehost.com/repos/
live = ssh://user@host.com//home/user/public_html
```

I read some information about this in http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths
But my problem is that i don't know how to use it.
My guess is that it should be something like this:

```
hg pull @live
```

Maybe i'm missing some documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [`hg help urls`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/urls):

> URLs can all be stored in your
>   configuration file with path aliases
>   under the [paths] section like so:
>
> ```
>   [paths]
>   alias1 = URL1
>   alias2 = URL2
>   ...
> ```
>
> You can then use the alias for any
>   command that uses a URL (for example
>   `hg pull alias1` will be treated as
>   `hg pull URL1`).
>
> Two path aliases are special because
>   they are used as defaults when you do
>   not provide the URL to a command:
>
> 1. default
> 2. default-push

Comment: i don't know why but i tried exactly that before and it didn't work. Now it works like i expected. Thank you.

Comment: The answer is pretty verbose! It could be as simple as, "do 'hg pull live', no @ required" :)